# Unexpected end of input error when configuring with flutterfire

Tags: flutter, firebase

I've been trying to integrate firebase into my flutter project, however I continually get this error when running the flutterfire configure script. The script runs when it is just ios, but not android.

I've blanked out specific identifiers with ////////

```
    % flutterfire configure
i Found 1 Firebase projects.                                                                                             
✔ Select a Firebase project to configure your Flutter application with · //////////// (////////)                             
✔ Which platforms should your configuration support (use arrow keys & space to select)? · android, ios                   
i Firebase android app com./////./// registered.                                                                    
i Firebase ios app com./////./// registered.                                                                   
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)

^

#0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1383:5)
#1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:501:7)
#2      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:36:10)
#3      JsonDecoder.convert (dart:convert/json.dart:612:36)
#4      FirebaseAndroidOptions.projectIdFromFileContents (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase/firebase_android_options.dart:29:29)
#5      FirebaseAndroidGradlePlugins.applyGoogleServicesPlugin (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase/firebase_android_gradle_plugins.dart:101:50)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FirebaseAndroidGradlePlugins.apply (package:flutterfire_cli/src/firebase/firebase_android_gradle_plugins.dart:240:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 17):

I fixed this error by the following steps:

1. Uninstall and Re-install or Update `flutterfire` via these commands

   - `dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli`
   - `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`
2. Delete the `google_services.json` file in the
   ***[project_folder]/android/app*** directory.
3. Re-run the flutterfire configure command

   - `flutterfire configure`

Comment: Thank you mate. I indeed needed to simply delete google_services and configure again.

Comment: Thanks man! Had done deactivate and reactivate but this is the first place telling to remove google_services. It worked here! Upvoted :)

Answer (score -1):

Solved by rebuilding the flutter application with a different file name. Don't know the exact problem, but this is my personal solution after trying everything else.